# Hacker rank linklist node deletion-one test case failing need to understand where is it going wrong

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

class SinglyLinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, node_data):
        self.data = node_data
        self.next = None

class SinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insert_node(self, node_data):
        node = SinglyLinkedListNode(node_data)

        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node


        self.tail = node

def print_singly_linked_list(node, sep, fptr):
    while node:
        fptr.write(str(node.data))

        node = node.next

        if node:
            fptr.write(sep)

#
# Complete the 'deleteNode' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER_SINGLY_LINKED_LIST.
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. INTEGER_SINGLY_LINKED_LIST llist
#  2. INTEGER position
#

#
# For your reference:
#
# SinglyLinkedListNode:
#     int data
#     SinglyLinkedListNode next
#
#

def deleteNode(llist, position):
    # Write your code here
    if llist is None: 
        llist=None
        return llist
    else:
        temp=llist
        index=0
        while index<position-1:
            temp=temp.next
            index+=1
        new_node=temp.next
        temp.next=new_node.next 
            
    return llist
            
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    llist_count = int(input())

    llist = SinglyLinkedList()

    for _ in range(llist_count):
        llist_item = int(input())
        llist.insert_node(llist_item)

    position = int(input())

    llist1 = deleteNode(llist.head, position)

    print_singly_linked_list(llist1, ' ', fptr)
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/delete-a-node-from-a-linked-list/problem?isFullScreen=true

I was trying to solve this hacker rank challenge but only 1 of the test cases are failing, i'm not sure why is it failing can anyone point out the error?

Test case:

7
11
12
8
18
16
5
18
0

Expected o/p:

12 8 18 16 5 18

As the method is outside the class, hence i'm not able to use the self.tail veriable then it would have been easy

Comment: `position == 0` is a special case for which the head of the linked list must be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work correctly when `position` is 0. In that case it acts as if `position` was 1 and removes the second node instead of the first. You'll have to deal with this case separately.

No problem, but:

- `llist=None` is useless where you have it, because the `if` condition had just asserted that `llist` was already `None`
- It is more pythonic to loop over a `range` than to have a `while` loop in which you increase a counter with `+= 1`.
- There is no need to use the `new_node` name (which is a strange name for a node that is about to be removed), as you can make the assignment to the `next` attribute directly.
- After an `if ... return` there is no need to have an `else` block; you can save one level of indentation here.
- The challenge guarantees that the list will not be empty, so in theory you don't need the first `if` condition. Still, I think it is a good habit to keep it in.
- If `position` would be an index that is out of range, then your code would produce an error. This is not really a problem, because the challenge guarantees that there are no such test cases, but it is still a good habit to foresee such cases.
- `temp` is not a very meaningful name. I'd suggest `prev` or `previous` to indicate that we aim to identify the node that *precedes* the node to remove.

Proposed code:

```
def deleteNode(llist, position):
    if not llist: # will not happen here, but good to have it
        return
    if position == 0:  # need to deal with this case separately
        return llist.next
    if llist.next:  # otherwise position is out of range
        prev = llist
        for _ in range(1, position):  # pythonic loop
            prev = prev.next
            if not prev.next:
                break  # position is out of range
        else:  # position is in range
            prev.next = prev.next.next             
    return llist
```